# How to disable Hibernate FK creation for a ManyToMany table, when referenced talbe does not have a PK

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have entities like

```java
@Entity
public class Entity1 {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(...)
   private long id;

   @ManyToMany(
      targetEntity = "entity2",
      fetch = LAZY
   )
   private Entity2 entity2;
}

@Entity
public class Entity2 {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(...)
   private long id;
}
```

The table `entity1` is already existing partitioned table without PK on whole partitioned table, but with PK on each partition. When hibernate initializes such mapping, it create or get tables like `entity1`, `entity2`, `entity1_entity2`. Then it tries to create FK from `entity1_entity2` to `entity1`, but it fails, because `entity1` does not have PK

The question is: are there any ways to disable FK creation for such a case? Or I should create an issue to Hibernate?

I'm using Hibernate 5.4.27, Java 15, Postgresql 12

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```java
import javax.persistence.ConstraintMode;

@Entity
public class Entity1 {

   // ...

   @ManyToMany(...)
   @JoinTable(
      name = "entity1_entity2",
      foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT),
      inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)
   )
   private Entity2 entity2;

}
```

It can also be disabled globally via the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.default_constraint_mode` option (`CONSTRAINT` (default value) or `NO_CONSTRAINT`). See additional information in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl).